# Мск, мща — этимология

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слов "мск" и "мща" (осёл)?

[Острожская библия](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006.pdf):
Псалмы.31:9

"Не будете яко конь и **мъскъ**, имъже несть разума" страница 904
2Царств.13:29

"и въсташа сынове цареви и вседе кожъдо на **мща** свое и бежаша" страница 483
Бытие.12:16

"И быша авраму овца говяда и ослята, рабы и рабыня и **мщата** и вельблюди" страница 39

Answer (score 1):

Только не МСК, а МЬСКЪ, в современном русском такого слова нет, есть остаток от него - мускус. Какая ж может быть этимология у церковно-славянских  односложных корней слов, которых нет в современном русском? Это не этимология, а семантика.

Вот Вам в помощь http://drevlit.ru/files/slovar1.pdf - словарь слов из Остромирова евангелия.

Мьшта (юс малый) – мул, лошак. (стр 414)

Мьска-мулица, мьскъ (иногда мескъ)– мул, лошак.

Мъскъ, мьскъ, москъ – мул.

Мъща – молодой меск, ослёнок, (стр.411)

**Т.е. мъскъ, мьскъ, москъ, мескъ – мул, лошак, а мъща (мьшта) - ослёнок, детёныш мула, лошака.**